# Yii2 View DateTime Format (d-m-Y H:i:s) But When Save/update in DB Change format to Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm Using Kartik DateTimePicker Extension

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Created')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(),[
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'Created',
        'name' => 'Created',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Created'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:ss',
            'todayHighlight' => true
        ]
    ]) 
?>
```

User fill the Create Date the format is

**d-m-Y H:i:s (like 24-09-2015 11:21:10)**

But when record save to database then Create Date Format change to

**Y-m-d H:i:s (like 2015-09-24 11:21:10)**

How can I change the date format on save/update of record

Comment: If you just change the column 'Created' to 'created_at', the code will be more pure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer using **AttributeBehavior**.

In my model class I've write the **behaviors code**:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                // update 1 attribute 'created' OR multiple attribute ['created','updated']
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created','updated'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated',
            ],
            'value' => function ($event) {
                return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->Created));
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

**My Model Class**

```
    namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\behaviors\AttributeBehavior;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "product".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $product_id
 * @property string $product_name
 * @property string $created
 * @property string $updated
 */
class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $csv_file;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created','updated'], // update 1 attribute 'created' OR multiple attribute ['created','updated']
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated', // update 1 attribute 'created' OR multiple attribute ['created','updated']
                ],
                'value' => function ($event) {
                    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->LastUpdated));
                },
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'product_id', 'product_name', created, updated], 'required'],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'product_id' => 'Product ID',
            'product_name' => 'Product Name',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'updated' => 'Updated',
        ];
    }
}
```

If input format is **d/m/Y** then you need to replace the **"/" by "-"**

**like:** input date(created): 10/09/2015

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$this->created)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to just add this code before save/update model in controller.

like,

```
// ICU format
$model->Created = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($_POST['modelName']['Created'], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); // 2014-10-06 15:22:34
```

OR

```
// PHP date()-format
$model->Created = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($_POST['modelName']['Created'], 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2014-10-06 15:22:34
```

For more information refer this [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-formatting.md#formatting-date-and-time-values-)

Comment: Is any other method to change the date format? like beforeSave()

Comment: my input is datetime not date

Comment: Thanks @gamitg. Solution found using behaviors

Comment: Used php:Y-m-d H:i:s format it changes in time. time will be increase by 2hours. can check once by execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

use in active form

'clientOptions' => ['alias' =>  'dd-mm-yyyy'],

use in active form

```
echo MaskedInput::widget([
'name' => 'input-31',
'clientOptions' => ['alias' =>  'date']]);
```

use class

Class yii\widgets\MaskedInput

Example

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
    'name' => 'input-31',
    'clientOptions' => ['alias' =>  'dd-mm-yyyy'],        ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simple code,
in behavior:

```
 public function behaviors() {
    return [
       [ 'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at'],
            ],
            // if you're using datetime instead of UNIX timestamp:
             'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
       ]
    ];
}
```

for rules:

```
 public function behaviors() {
    return [
       [ 'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at'],
            ],
            // if you're using datetime instead of UNIX timestamp:
             'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
       ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            ],
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain *why* and *how* your code snippet provides an answer to the question? Thanks.